# MySQL trigger locks table

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, locking

I have created trigger in MySQL to update data but problem is as soon as I deploy trigger, it's locking tables and applications using these tables are not able to access.

### Edit

Trigger I have created will insert data in a table

```
USE app ; //db user n database1
DELIMITER $
Create trigger Insert_Data After insert on clients for each row
Begin

insert into database2.customers` 
values('1', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'US', 'USD', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'America/New_York', NULL, '0', '0', NULL
);

End $
DELIMITER ;
```

Once above trigger deployed, clients table is not accessible by a website/GUI that inserts data from a submit option on UI page.

### Edit

I am adding the SQLError logs, Also apologise for not mentioning I am inserting data in another database using the trigger in one database.

`production.ERROR: [stacktrace] 2022-02-25 05:54:43 SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1142 INSERT command denied to user XXXXX`

What can I do for this case where trigger should add record in database2 when executed from database1?

Comment: What does the trigger do? Can you show the code for this trigger? What do you mean when you say others cannot access the tables? Do they get an error? What is that error message?

Comment: Sure will add code in minute

Comment: @BillKarwin Added code, When GUI tries to fire a insert command then I am seeing error `500` on web page

Comment: 500 is not descriptive enough. It is an http status that means the app suffered some internal error. You need to find out what is the SQL error. That will probably mean checking for error status after every SQL call in your app and logging the error message.

Comment: Sure  reason I am confirming the behaviour is when I drop the trigger everything is normal.

Comment: I can't tell what the cause is from your description. I would at least need to know what the SQL error message is. Good luck!

Comment: Sure, Thanks for your time and responses, will try to fetch the SQL error log

Comment: The MySQL Server error log doesn't include errors for individual SQL statements, so it probably won't be useful in this case. You need the code in the application to log error after the SQL statements that are being blocked.

Comment: Very strange trigger. It inserts a row into `customers` each time when a row is inserted into `clients` table. But this row content does not depend on the values inserted into `clients`, the trigger inserts absolutely the same row each time. If some column which is assigned to non-NULL value (or their combination) is defined as primary key or unique then the trigger will cause duplicate violation error (error code 1062 SQLSTATE 23000) which will rollback the insertion into both tables and will return the error code into your program. This error may be a reason of your HTTP error 500.

Comment: Provide the task itself, not only the way which you decide to apply for to solve this task. Post (as well-formatted textual code) `CREATE TABLE` for both tables, `INSERT INTO client` query and desired final state for `customers` table. If some autoassigned value (in `client`) must be inserted to 2nd table - point this.

Comment: So it's an **access violation** error. You should use [SHOW GRANTS FOR XXXX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-grants.html) to see the privileges of that user (see the link for syntax details). I expect the privileges granted to this user will not include privileges to insert to `database2.customers`.

Comment: Also I notice in your trigger, it looks like there is an extra back-tick following `database2.customers`. Is that actually in your trigger code? Or is it a typo you made when posting this question?

Comment: @BillKarwin sorry its a typo mistake in question not in code, I am afraid regarding the grants as I don't have access to DB server

Comment: You do have access, or else you wouldn't have been able to create the trigger. You can run SHOW GRANTS in the same query interface.

Comment: @BillKarwin I have accessed the Grants and found only that database users have the access, I tried to add the access permission to another database but got access denied error. Statement that I run `GRANT ALL ON Db2.* TO 'DB1'@'localhost';`

Comment: Can you please help me with this on how can I add the grant access to DB1 to access DB2

Comment: You cannot use your current user to grant privileges to itself that it does not have. You will need to get the site administrator to do this for you.

Comment: Alternatively, use tables only in the schema you do have privileges to use. I.e. do not write a trigger that attempts to insert into a table in `Db2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summary of the comment thread above: that the origin of the error was this:

> Syntax error or access violation

The MySQL user calling the trigger does not have INSERT privilege to the `database2.customers` table. The user only had privileges on the primary database, where the `clients` table was stored.

An error in an SQL statement executed in a trigger causes the action that spawned the trigger to fail.

After the MySQL user was granted INSERT privilege to tables in `database2`, the errors stopped and the issue was resolved.